# Recent App Icon shows the default icon Android Studio

Tags: android, android-icons, appicon

[image]

I've update the images both Round and square icon works perfectly but in the recent application the default app icon is showing.

Manifest.xml have following code

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: if this is  "ic_launcher_round" the icon you need just clean the project or Invalidate cashes the android studio

Comment: that's work. Thanks @Abdelazizrefaat